# Binary Logistic regression results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, regression-coefficients, regression-strategies

Is it correct to find that an explanatory variable was found to be statistically significant with the chi-square test but insignificant with the logistic regression analysis model?

Comment: Does your logistic regression model only have one explanatory variable in it?

Comment: No it has several explanatory variables,about 10 of them.

Comment: It sounds as if you are running the risk of double dipping.  You can't use associations with $Y$ to decide which variables to test for associations with $Y$.  Besides that, adjusted and unadjusted (for covariates) analyses naturally differ.

Comment: Does this mean that the results might be faulty or the approach wrong?

Comment: Correct.  Look at some of the rules of thumb for the required sample size as a function of the number of _candidate_ predictors, and pre-specify a full model and use it as the basis for your conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Cleared up and partially answered in comments:

> This logistic regression model has several explanatory variables, about 10 of them.

– Etta

> It sounds as if you are running the risk of double dipping. You can't use associations with Y to decide which variables to test for associations with Y. Besides that, adjusted and unadjusted (for covariates) analyses naturally differ.

– Frank Harrell

> Does this mean that the results might be faulty or the approach wrong?

– Etta

> Correct. Look at some of the rules of thumb for the required sample size as a function of the number of candidate predictors, and pre-specify a full model and use it as the basis for your conclusions.

– Frank Harrell

See also [Variable selection for predictive modeling really needed in 2016?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215154/variable-selection-for-predictive-modeling-really-needed-in-2016)