# what's the efficient way to do feature selection when I have 500 variables

Tags: r, feature-selection, feature-engineering

my datasets have 500 variables, how to quickly verify which independent variables are significant to my dependent variable or my model?  what I usually do is to import some of them, and see which one has a small p-value.

Comment: Try to run a lasso regression with increasing weight on the penalty terms. It performs well in variable selection task

Comment: What question are you trying to answer? What do you mean when you ask if they are significant? More context is needed; what makes sense in one circumstance may not in another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable selection for predictive modeling really needed in 2016?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215154/variable-selection-for-predictive-modeling-really-needed-in-2016)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to answer this without more information about your data and question, but conducting univariate tests and evaluating the p values ignores more complex intercorrelations and multivariate interactions that may be present. Using regularization during cross validation, as a commenter noted, is a more principled way to go about feature selection.